# Transpose row four columns at a time (row to 4-column matrix)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, offset, transpose, worksheet-function

I have data in the following layout (each 'digit' in its own column but all in Row 1 of Excel):

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

How might I easily convert this to:

```
1 2 3 4  
5 6 7 8  
9 1 2 3  
4 5 6 7
```

I want every four pieces of data to be added, in separate columns, to new rows underneath one another.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your data starts in A1, please try in A3, copied across to D and down to suit:

```
=OFFSET($A$1,,COLUMN()+4*(ROW()-2)-5)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is already answered, but just for fun, here's a version that's non-volatile and doesn't need to be placed in a particular location:

```
=INDEX($A$1:$P$1,4*(ROW($A$1:$D$4)-1)+COLUMN($A$1:$D$4))
```

Replace the range `$A$1:$P$1` above with whatever range you want to rearrange, and enter as an array formula. (Select the entire 4x4 range, type the formula, and press ctrl-shift-enter when you're finished rather than just enter.) Note that `$A$1:$D$4` is a constant, used to obtain the sequential numbers.

One more way - a shorter formula but requiring some setup:

Create a named range, let's call it Matrix1:

```
1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1
```

You can put the matrix on another, possibly hidden, worksheet, or you can just use an array constant:

```
={1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0;0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0;0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0;0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1}
```

And another, let's call it Matrix2:

```
1 0 0 0
0 1 0 0
0 0 1 0
0 0 0 1
1 0 0 0
0 1 0 0
0 0 1 0
0 0 0 1
1 0 0 0
0 1 0 0
0 0 1 0
0 0 0 1
1 0 0 0
0 1 0 0
0 0 1 0
0 0 0 1
```

or:

```
={1,0,0,0;0,1,0,0;0,0,1,0;0,0,0,1;1,0,0,0;0,1,0,0;0,0,1,0;0,0,0,1;1,0,0,0;0,1,0,0;0,0,1,0;0,0,0,1;1,0,0,0;0,1,0,0;0,0,1,0;0,0,0,1}
```

Then the formula is just:

```
=MMULT(Matrix1*$A$2:$P$2,Matrix2)
```

Again, select the entire 4x4 range and enter as an array formula.

You could, of course, enter the array constants into the formula directly, but that gets unwieldy:

```
=MMULT({1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0;0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0;0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0;0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1}*$A$2:$P$2,{1,0,0,0;0,1,0,0;0,0,1,0;0,0,0,1;1,0,0,0;0,1,0,0;0,0,1,0;0,0,0,1;1,0,0,0;0,1,0,0;0,0,1,0;0,0,0,1;1,0,0,0;0,1,0,0;0,0,1,0;0,0,0,1})
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this formula much easier to deal with.

```
=INDEX($A:$A,ROW(A1)*4-4+COLUMN(A1))
```

For details:
https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/3360-excel-transpose-every-5-rows.html